# Show and Hide UserControls (BringToFront/SendToBack)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a "tricky" UI. Part of what I need to do is easily show and hide various UserControls. Generally one control will occupy the entire main window when needed, the other's will hide.

In WinForms I used to simply use SendToBack and BringToFront and easily showed the control I wanted to show. Now I have no clue. Played around with zorder but that didn't seem to work.

I'm thinking maybe put all the controls I want on the main window, then pro-grammatically  resize them and remove the unused ones... or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`, `Hidden` or `Visbible` depending on whether you want the controls removed, hidden or shown.

As @AresAvatar points out `Collapsed` removes the control completely so it takes up no space, this means that other controls may move around the container. If the position of elements is important then using `Hidden` will be the better option.

[UIElement.Visibility Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN
[Visibility Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: In some cases you might want to use Hidden instead of Collapsed, in case you do not want your container to resize when things appear or disappear.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something kind of fancy. What I have done is use a DockPanel; I am making use of <panel>.Children.Remove and Add functions. I am also making use of Opacity; I fade out the component to remove and fade in the panel to add. Looks cool. Too bad as a newbie to wpf it took hours to figure out what might work, and there is probably better ways too... oh well.